# Cant set up Swap Memory

Tags: swap, memory, drive

My system was recently locking up, and I realized that all my ram was all used up. I then inserted an old Hard drive and made an 8gb swap partition to compensate. Swap memory is "not avaliable" which means I need to activate it. How do I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to accomplish this permanently is adding a correct line in your `/etc/fstab` file pointing to the swap partition you created. Then run `swapon -a`.

Such a line in `fstab` should look similar to this:

```
UUID=4139a640-c32e-4e88-b275-75c77722da7c none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Find the UUID of your swap partition by running `blkid` and replace it accordingly.

It is also possible to activate it temporarily using `swapon` by pointing it to the partition directly (see manpage). After reboot it will not be activated again automatically.

Comment: It worked! :D Many kudos to you, been trying to work this out for ages! I have now got 8 gb of swap in my system monitor:
http://i989.photobucket.com/albums/af17/adamjoh/Screenshotfrom2012-09-14193102.png
Btw, when i typed "swapon" i got a list of items, i actually had to type "swapon -a". Ill go reboot now and see what happens ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Setup swap partition on your drive (You can as well setup Swap file on your current drive)... So: start Gparted and set a partition and make it as swap

2) You can activate it manually by command:

```
swapon PARTITION_NAME
```

where PARTITION_NAME is something like /dev/sdb1 (according to your drives, check it out correctly)

Now you should find mention of this swap in `/proc/swaps`

3) You can activate it permanently by editing `/etc/fstab`
Ad line like this:

```
PARTITION_NAME  swap  swap defaults 0 0
```

where again  PARTITION_NAME is something like /dev/sdb1 (according to your drives, check it out correctly)

Comment: Looking at the other answer: using UUID instead of /dev/* name is good idea... Also after adding it to /etc/fstab you need to do `swapon -a`